# About continuity of the distribution function of $X+Y$ when they are independent and one has continuous distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity, quantile-function

I want to prove that if $X, Y$ are independent random variables and the distibution function of $X$ is continuous (it doesn't really matter wether this is for $Y$) then the distribution function of $X+Y$ is continuous. I have thought of using that $F$ continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $F^{-1}$ is strictly increasing but cannot get to anything correct.

This is part of an exercise from my Probability Theory class.

Comment: Are you familiar with Lebesgue's decomposition theorem? That is, a probability measure can be written uniquely (up to probability one) as the sum of an absolutely continuous measure, a singular continuous measure, and a discrete measure?

Comment: I know about the descompostion in discrete and absolutely continuous, but nothing about singular continuous

Comment: Hint: Show that if a continuous function has limits at $\pm \infty$, then it is uniformly continuous. In particular, the cdf of $X$ is uniformly continuous. Using independence, decompose $P(z -\delta < X+Y \le z)$ in a way that lets you exploit this uniform continuity to argue that $P(X + Y \le z)$ is left continuous.